# Browser unique field on the server side

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, httprequest

Doing the following:

```
require ("http").createServer (function (req, res) {
   /* get the browser unique id */
}).listen (8080);
```

Does the `req` object contain something unique for each browser session?

For example: having two browser tabs, the unique field should be the same. But accessing the same page from two different browsers (there should be two different values: one for each browser).

I suppose that such a field is presend in `req.socket` object. When using *socket.io* library I  there is a `client.id` field.

Can I do this without setting cookies on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is written in Node.JS [API documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage), the `req` paramenter is used to access headers, data and response status(see HTTP response codes).

Inspecting the `req` object for each browser is too hard because of the number of properties and methods(a lot of discussion here). But if you would inspect the headers(`req.headers`) you would see a small difference between `req` objects. For example I opened a new Google Chrome Icognito Window and a new Private Windows in Firefox and these the headers:

```
{ host: 'lvh.me:8000',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
{ host: 'lvh.me:8000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8' }
```

So, the only properties that are same in both objects are `host` and `connection`. But the host could be different if you call the server with a different subdomain(For example: `www`)

If you could inspect the whole object, probably you would find out more about each browser.